# How to rename H2 SQL column with reserved keyword

Tags: sql, h2

How do I rename a column of MY_TABLE from *offset* to *OFFSET* in SQL with H2 dialect?

When I'm using `ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE RENAME "offset" TO "OFFSET";` it gives me the error message:

```
SQL-Error [42001] [42001]: Syntax Error in SQL command "ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE RENAME ""offset""[*] TO ""OFFSET"""; expected "COLUMN, CONSTRAINT, TO"
Syntax error in SQL statement "ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE RENAME ""offset""[*] TO ""OFFSET"""; expected "COLUMN, CONSTRAINT, TO"; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE RENAME "offset" TO "OFFSET" [42001-199]
```

Comment: `alter table my_table alter column "offset" rename to "OFFSET"`? See [H2 - ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN](https://www.h2database.com/html/commands.html#alter_table_alter_column).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax for H2 is

```sql
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE RENAME COLUMN "offset" TO "OFFSET";
```

Please note that H2 1.4.199 is an old unsupported version of H2.

Comment: Thanks man! I know that this is an old version, but we have hardware in place that uses it which is beyond our influence.